# Computing a Fourier transform and imaginary part dependence

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I would like to compute the following Fourier transform:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (1 + (x+it)^2)^{-s} e^{i x \xi} dx$$
and to explicitly see the dependence in $s$, in particular the imaginary part. Since the variables are nonreal, I am not so sure what kind of change of variables can be done.

Comment: It is unusual for a Fourier transform to have $\xi$ appearing outside of the $\exp(ix\xi)$ term. How did that arise?

Comment: @eyeballfrog You are right, it is a (pretty important) mistake: it is not there, it is now corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the value of $t$? In particular, do we know whether $|t|$ is larger or smaller than 1?

Comment: Oh, it's worth noting that the imaginary part of this integral is always zero. To see this, split into the $x < 0$ and $x > 0$ cases and then change variables to $x = -y$ in the negative case. You'll see that the $x$ and $y$ integrals are complex conjugates of each other, so their sum is purely real.

Comment: @eyeballfrog $t$ is a constant that may be chosen pretty freely, so we can assume whatever we prefer to ensure convergence or good behavior

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thanks for the nice comment on the imaginary part! Mostly, I am interested in the size (of the absolute value) of this integral, when the imaginary part of $s$ grows

Comment: You don't have to change the coordinates. Standard use of Jordan's lemma together with the residue theorem allows you to calculate the interval (for Re s > 0).

Comment: @meler Residue theorem is going to run into problems if $s$ isn't an integer.

Comment: This could involve Meijer G functions (just guessing)

Comment: Doing some checking on $t$ values, everything's fine for $|t|<1$. For $|t| \ge 1$, the integration contour runs through the branch cut of $\ln$. Not sure how that should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

This is expressible with the Bessel function $$K_p(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}r^{p-1}e^{-(ar+\frac{b}{r})}dr.$$ To see this, apply $$\frac{1}{A^s}=
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-Ar}\frac{r^{s-1}}{\Gamma(s)}dr$$ to $A=1+(x+it)^2$ and then Fubini, landing on a Gaussian integral. Computation goes well, but I am afraid to make mistakes for the exact  expression of  $a$ and $b$ in terms of $\xi$ and $t.$ I have found $$p=s-\frac{1}{2},\ a=1+3t^2, \ b=\frac{\xi^2}{4}.$$

Note that $K_p(a,b)$ can be expressed in terms of $K_p(t)=K_p(t,t)$ with $t=\sqrt{ab}.$

Comment: I found $I=e^{t\xi}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(s)}K_p(a,b).$

Comment: Note that this integral method only works for $|t| < 1$. For $t > 1$, the integral for $A^{-s}$ diverges when $x < \sqrt{t^2-1}$. Also, I get $I = [2\sqrt{\pi}/\Gamma(s)]e^{\xi t} |\xi/2|^{s-1/2}K_{s-1/2}(\xi)$ using this method

Comment: So I have been sloppy in my calculations. Congratulations. For $|t|<1$ it seems that $I$ is an analytic function of $t$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Also, since the integrand is analytic in the strip $|\mathrm{Im}[z]| < 1$, we have that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty [1 + (x + i t)^2]^{-s} \exp[i\xi (x+i t)]dx$ is independent of $t$. So we could have gotten the $t$ dependence without doing the integral.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. Where can I find the explicit formula linking $K_p(a,b)$ and $K_p(t)$?

Comment: Just do the linear change of variable $r=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}u.$